Declare aliases for counts which use the same column with Laravel's Eloquent method loadCount()
It is possible to load count of relations for already fetched model, like that:
$post->loadCount([
    'comments',
    'something',
    'else',
]);

Now I want to add constraints to some counts:
$post->loadCount([
    'comments' => fn($q) => $q->where('approved', true),
    'something',
    'else',
]);

Great, but now I need count for approved and not approved comments. And I'm stuck.
$post->loadCount([
    'comments' => fn($q) => $q->where('approved', true), // as comments_approved
    'comments' => fn($q) => $q->where('approved', false), // as comments_pending
    'something',
    'else',
]);

This of course does not work because comments is defined twice in array.
Also because loadCount() expects relation name as array key, I cannot use comments_approved because this is not a relation.
Is there some other option in loadCount or different approach?

If you only want count for approve & non-approve then what is the purpose something & else in your last query? Can you please clarify?

Topically related pages: Laravel Eloquent Lazy Eager Load Count and count with load Laravel and Why loadCount() introduced and its actual usage into laravel

Like the withCount, you can also alias the relation name in loadCount
   $post->loadCount([
      'comments as comments_approved' => fn($q) => $q->where('approved', true),
      'comments as comments_pending' => fn($q) => $q->where('approved', false),
      'something'
  ]);


For your information, I am in discussions with other curators about potentially merging your answer to Why loadCount() introduced and its actual usage into laravel.  Your insights would be unique and helpful on that page.  That question is suitably asked as a canonical page for all new questions on the topic of loadCount().  If your answer is moved, will you be open to editing your answer to more broadly/generally explaining this implementation with aliased counts?

I believe this new question will serve as a good sign post for the older canonical page.

Hi @mickmackusa, I will be pleased to bring more details about this implementation.

I've spoken with Dharman and there will be no page merging.  If you'd like to answer that older page to describe the implementation of this answer (in a generalized way), I think that would help future readers to understand how to use this method with an aliased count columns.
